# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Images#index

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

newbie here stuck on nested resources. I have a `image.rb` model, which stores images onto the cloudinary CDN. After getting all that working, I decided I needed to categorize the images, so i created a `category.rb` model which just has a name really, for now anyways.

I have been slowly working through errors after adding a `category` model and controller/views and all was going okay, until this one. I'm stumped lol. Have been googling around for a few hours now and decided I'm at a wall... so, naturally I come here, hoping someone could enlighten me. Thanks in advance! <3 SO

Here is the error (it is currently throwing it on the `"edit"` link, but i think it will throw it on the `"delete"` as well after i get edit working, so I have been changing them there as well):

```
No route matches {:category_id=>nil, :id=>#<Image id: 16, title: "mario", description: "i belong to category 2!", upload_date: nil, created_at: "2014-03-15 01:13:54", updated_at: "2014-03-15 01:13:54", category_id: 2>} missing required keys: [:category_id]

<td><%= link_to "Show", [@category, image] %></td>
<% if admin? %>
        <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_category_image_path(@category, image) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Delete", [@category, image], confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete \"#{image.title}\"?", method: :delete %></td>
<% end %>
    </tr>
```

Here is my `Image` model:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attachment :image_file, accept: [:jpg, :png, :gif]
  validates :title, presence: true

  belongs_to :category
end
```

Here is the `Category` model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
end
```

Here are the controllers for each:

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_admin, except: [:index, :show]
  def index
    @images = Image.all
  end

  def show
    @image = Image.find(params[:category_id])
  end

  def new
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @image = @category.images.build(image_params)
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @image = @category.images.build(image_params)

    if @image.save
      render "show"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @image = Image.find(params[:id])
    @image.destroy
    redirect_to images_path
  end

  def edit
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @image = @category.images.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @image = @category.images.find(params[:id])

    if @image.update(image_params)
      render "show"
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  private

  def image_params
    params.require(:image).permit(:title, :description, :image_file, :category_id)
  end
end
```

and the `Category` controller

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def show
    redirect_to category_images_path(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)

    if @category.save
      redirect_to @category
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @category.destroy
    redirect_to categories_path
  end

  def edit
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])

    if @category.update(category_params)
      redirect_to @category
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  private
  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:title)
  end
end
```

Here is the routes file:

```
Portfolio::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :blogs

  resources :categories do
    resources :images
  end


  root "index#index"

  #attachinary
  mount Attachinary::Engine => "/attachinary"
end
```

From googling around I kept running into people having problems with it being related to `form partials` so here is the `_form.html.erb` I am using for `Image` just in case it's needed:

```
<%= form_for([@category, @image]) do |f| %>
    <%= render "error" %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label "Upload image" %><br>
    <%= f.attachinary_file_field :image_file %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

ImagesController

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_category
  before_action :set_image, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_admin, except: [:index, :show]
  def index
    @images = @category.images.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @image = @category.images.new
  end

  def create
    @image = @category.images.new(image_params)

    if @image.save
      render "show"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @image.destroy
    redirect_to images_path
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @image.update(image_params)
      render "show"
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  private

  def load_category
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
  end

  def set_image
    @image = @category.images.find(params[:id])
  end

  def image_params
    params.require(:image).permit(:title, :description, :image_file, :category_id)
  end
end
```

Try to use the `before_action` callback to set your necessary instance variables. Here I loaded the category and the images via a private method. This saves a lot time. You can even see this when you generate scaffolding.

`before_filter` has been aliased as `before_action` to make it clearer of its function.

The root path is usually defined on the second line of routes so its clear.

Your named paths doesn't seem like the problem. It is mainly your images controller

I suggest you generate a new rails app using scaffolding just to look at it's controllers.

```
rails g scaffolding images
```

Comment: hi, i tried adding your code, and now i'm getting "Couldn't find Image with id=15 [WHERE "images"."category_id" = ?]" when trying to delete or update an image etc. url is http://localhost:3000/categories/3/images/15http://localhost:3000/categories/3/images/15

also when i try to create a new one it tells me error title can't be  blank, even when i specify a title...?

Comment: You didn't set @category in your show method - that view was from show.html.erb I presume. The second problem..stack trace would be nice - but I think you have mismatched ids of category and image.

Comment: `@category` is added to all methods using the `load_category` private method in a before_action